# Azure Dev Build Release Test Execution getting aborted

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, coded-ui-tests

Whenever I try to run the coded UI test in On-premise agent machine with Azure build-release pipeline my tests are getting aborted since yesterday. I have changed nothing on the release pipeline and build definition.

Below is the error message I am getting in the release pipeline test run console :-

```
2019-04-24T06:48:27.4475294Z test settings id : 1026822
2019-04-24T06:48:27.4475397Z Build location: C:\agent\_work\r1\a
2019-04-24T06:48:27.4475515Z Build Id: 5133
2019-04-24T06:48:28.0903047Z Test run with Id 1038940 associated
2019-04-24T06:48:37.6929302Z Received the command : Start
2019-04-24T06:48:37.6944608Z TestExecutionHost.ProcessCommand. Start Command handled
2019-04-24T06:48:58.8010958Z Received the command : Stop
2019-04-24T06:48:58.8011508Z TestExecutionHost.ProcessCommand. Stop Command handled
2019-04-24T06:48:58.8011845Z SliceFetch Aborted. Moving to the TestHostEnd phase
2019-04-24T06:48:58.9585180Z Please use this link to analyze the test run : 'test run URL'
2019-04-24T06:48:58.9585816Z Test run '1038940' is in 'Aborted' state with 'Total Tests' : 3 and 'Passed Tests' : 0.
2019-04-24T06:48:58.9604537Z ##[error]Test run is aborted. Logging details of the run logs.
2019-04-24T06:48:58.9606187Z ##[error]System.Exception: The test run was aborted, failing the task.
2019-04-24T06:48:59.0826921Z ##########################################################################
2019-04-24T06:48:59.1608855Z ##[section]Finishing: Test run for Test plans
```

I am running those test from past 6 months and I have not changed anything on the build or release pipeline and suddenly I am getting the above error on azure release pipeline test run console while triggering the run.

Note: this happened since yesterday(April 24, 2019). Till Monday(April 22, 2019) everything was working fine.

I believe there might be some changes from Microsoft end but I am not sure about that.
I am running the test on Windows 10 environment.

Comment: Apparently, the problem was from microsoft end and did not have to do anything to fix it. The test runs are is working now.

Comment: It seems that it is caused by Azure DevOps event, said by Microsoft Team